# nginx truncates responses to external requests but not local

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog

I've configured nginx to do port forwarding to Ghost blog that's running on the same machine. When I open localhost, nginx returns everything correctly.

However when I hit the server from the outside, my scripts get truncated. Any ideas why that might be? I noticed plenty of questions about truncated responses but not a single one mentioning that happening only on remote requests.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any proxies, firewalls, CDNs, etc? Please describe your whole environment accurately. Please also edit your question to show a curl with response headers (usually curl -i) from both the instance and an external machine, and in each case please show corresponding access and error logs - Nginx and if applicable PHP or whatever. Make sure it's well formatted so people can follow them, you'll get more help that way.

Comment: Thank you, @Tim, it's working now (was getting ready to post all info you mentioned and almost accidentally fixed it).

Answer (score 0):

Out of desperation I set

```
proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
```

and it worked. I'm not sure why there was a difference on local requests vs remote ones but now it seems to work.